# Rails 3 migration error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

Whenever I create and run a new migration, my earliest migration automatically starts executing and gives me the following error:-
"rake aborted! An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:  Mysql2::Error: Table 'xyz' already exists"
Due to the this error my rake db:migrate does not run and rather I have to use rake db:migrate:up VERSION=123xyz for my new migration. What shall I do to remove this error , so that my previous miration doesn't run everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

drop this table manually in the mysql console

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if your Gemfile is updated.
See Listing 1.18 (scroll above to see the same a similar error message the author addresses):

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning#code:gemfile_sqlite_heroku

Inside the GemFile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.5'

gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.3.2', :group => :development
```

Comment: HI . I am sorry but I forgot to mention that I am using MySql for my rails app